# Ruby Ocra executable fatal error on different windows version

Tags: ruby, ocra

I made a pretty simple program for adding to and organizing an array of book authors/titles.  I only have one require at the top which is a module I created.  The code is all just standard ruby with no gems or anything implemented.

```
require_relative 'pairs2d'
```

I used ocra to turn it into an executable, and the .exe worked fine on my windows 7 computer (which has Ruby installed).  When I put the .exe on another computer and ran it, I received a fatal error.  The other computer is Windows XP, and it does not have Ruby installed.

This was the build after entering > ocra loonalibrary.rb

```
Including 53 encoding support files (3349504 bytes, use --no-enc to exclude)

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
=== Building loonalibrary.exe
=== Adding user-supplied source files
=== Adding ruby executable ruby.exe
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/zlib1.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/LIBEAY32.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/SSLEAY32.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/libffi-6.dll
=== Adding library files
=== Compressing 9780669 bytes
=== Finished building loonalibrary.exe (2478492 bytes)
```

The error from console when I ran this on the Windows XP computer without Ruby installed:

```
FATAL ERROR: Failed to create process (C:\DOCUME~1\mike\LOCALS~1\Temp\ocr6CF.tmp\bin\ruby.exe): 193
```

Is ocra sensitive to windows version or is this some other problem?  If anyone knows a fix to this problem, I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Build application with Ruby-x64.
When I build application with ruby-x32, problem was gone.
I think OCRA take current Ruby and include to aplication package. Windows XP dosen't support x64 app.