# Can't run exes made with ocra -- FATAL ERROR: Failed to create process

Tags: ruby, ocra

I'm trying to package a Ruby program as an .exe on a Windows computer using OCRA. When I tried to use it to create the executable for my program, it threw a weird error at runtime. I tried it with a simple Hello World program, and the error persisted.

I put the following in `helloworld.rb`:

```
puts "Hello, World!"
```

Then, I ran the file through OCRA:

```
H:\ocra test>ocra --no-dep-run helloworld.rb
=== Detected gem did_you_mean-1.1.0 (loaded, files)
===     14 files, 32780 bytes
=== Detected gem ocra-1.3.8 (loaded, files)
===     5 files, 291748 bytes
=== Including 59 encoding support files (3918740 bytes, use --no-enc to exclude)

=== Building helloworld.exe
=== Adding user-supplied source files
=== Adding ruby executable ruby.exe
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libgmp-10.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libffi-6.dll
=== Adding library files
=== Compressing 7908093 bytes
=== Finished building helloworld.exe (1919669 bytes)
```

However, when I tried to run this executable, I got the following message:

```
H:\ocra test>helloworld.exe
FATAL ERROR: Failed to create process (C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\ocr9C6D.tmp\bin\ruby.exe): 14001
```

Note: This is not a duplicate of [this person's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413073/ruby-ocra-executable-fatal-error-on-different-windows-version) which has the same error message. I am unable to run the EXE on the computer that generated it, whereas the person who asked the linked question was having issues running it on *other* computers.

Here are the versions of Ruby and OCRA, both of which I believe are the latest version:

```
H:\ocra test>ruby --version
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x64-mingw32]
H:\ocra test>ocra --version
Ocra 1.3.8
```

I'm on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

I also tried running it without the --no-dep-run flag, running the exe on my C: drive instead of H:, and running it in a command prompt with local administrator privileges. All gave the same error message.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by uninstalling Ruby and installing an older version (namely 2.3.3) via [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/). There seems to be an issue with 2.4.1 and ocra. I tested on a couple of fresh computers, and 2.4.1 didn't work even with a fresh install.

Answer (score 3):

There's now an updated Ocra 1.3.9 which fixes the issue.

Comment: However this version introduces a new problem: it can't produce 32 bit exe's within a 32 bit Ruby environment: https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/124.

Comment: Aah, I didn't realize that. I've uploaded 1.3.10 built with a 32-bit compiler.

Comment: I am getting the same error with 2.7.2 . Any suggestions?
Using  below version -->
ocra (1.3.11) -->

ruby 2.7.2p137